# Url blocked by robots.txt message in Google Webmaster

Tags: robots.txt

I've a wordpress site in root domain. Now, i've added a forum in subfolder as mydomain/forum
which makes a sitemap as follows: mydomain/forum/sitemap_index.xml.
Submitting that sitemap to google, It sounds google can't access sub-sitemaps with the message of "Url blocked by robots.txt" -  Value: mydomain/forum/sitemap-forums.xml?page=1 --- Value: mydoamin/forum/sitemap-index.xml?page=1.

This is my robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins
Disallow: /wp-content/cache
Disallow: /wp-content/themes
Disallow: /trackback
Disallow: /feed
Disallow: /comments
Disallow: /category/*/*
Disallow: */trackback
Disallow: */feed
Disallow: */comments
Disallow: /*?*
Disallow: /*?
Allow: /wp-content/uploads


# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Allow: /*

Sitemap: mydomain/sitemap_index.xml
Sitemap: mydomain/forum/sitemap_index.xml
```

What should i add to robots.txt? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, I'm assuming 'mydomain' in your example is a stand-in for the scheme plus fully qualified domain name, correct?  (e.g. "http://www.whatever.com", not "whatever.com" or "www.whatever.com") I figure this must be the case because you have it in the Google error message in the same format.

The error message suggests that Google is getting the URL from somewhere other than your robots.txt file. The robots.txt file lists the sitemap URL as:

```
mydomain/forum/sitemap_index.xml
```

but the error message shows that Google is trying to load the URL:

```
mydomain/forum/sitemap-index.xml?page=1
```

This second URL is getting blocked, because your robots.txt file blocks any URL that contains a question mark:

```
Disallow: /*?*
Disallow: /*?
```

(Incidentally, these two lines do exactly the same thing. You can safely delete the first one) Google should still be able to read the sitemap file using the simpler URL however, so the pages will probably still be crawled. If you really want to get rid of the error message, you could always add:

```
Allow: /forum/sitemap-index.xml?page=1
```

This will override the disallows for just the sitemap URL. (This will work on Google at least - YMMV for any other search engines)

Comment: Thanks. As i see in my sitemap-index.xml, there are some links like sitemap-thread.xml?page=1 and sitemap-forum.xml?page=1 and .... So, with your help i'm gonna try this: Allow: /forum/sitemap*?* (maybe there will be page2,page3,... in the future). Also it sounds i have to wait some time (=some hours) for google to recheck it. Am i right?

Comment: Even just "Allow: /forum/sitemap" should work, at least on Google. For Googlebot, longer rules (in terms of character count) take precedence over shorter rules. The pattern "/forum/sitemap" is longer than "/*?" so it takes priority. And yes, Googlebot can take a while to notice your new robots.txt file. Expect it to take several days, though you might get lucky.